# Angle and distance of defined inner vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let the vectors **u** and **v** be vectors in R$^4$. The inner product space is defined by

$<u, v> = 2u$<sub>1</sub>$v$<sub>1</sub> $+  u$<sub>2</sub>$v$<sub>2</sub> $+ u$<sub>3</sub>$v$<sub>3</sub> $ + 3u$<sub>4</sub>$v$<sub>4</sub>

When **u** $= (2, -2, 4, 2)$ and  **v** = $(4, 1, 4, 2)$ find the angle and distance between **u** and **v**.

Now the angle is normally defined by $\arccos$ **u** ∙ **v**/||**u**|| ||**v**||.  Would I still use the dot product answer of $26$ or the $<u, v>$ calculation of $42$?

Then for calculating the norm such as $<u, u>$<sup>1/2</sup> do I sub in **u** in the place of **v** which $ = \sqrt40$ or apply with itself $ = \sqrt72$. Which method is correct?

Then how does distance work when it is normally $<u-v, u-v>$<sup>1/2</sup>? I got the answer of 3 but I am not confident that is correct. Thanks.

Comment: You should use $\langle u,v\rangle$ and the corresponding norm, not the standard Euclidean inner product and norm.

Answer (score 1):

Any inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$ induces a unique norm $\|.\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}$ by $\|u\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}:=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$. As each inner product and its induced norm satisfy the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq\|u\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}
\|v\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}$$
one may define the angle $\angle_{\langle.,.\rangle}(u,v)$ between $u$ and $v$ in respect to $\langle.,.\rangle$ via
$$\cos\bigl(\angle_{\langle.,.\rangle}(u,v)\bigr)=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\|_{\langle.,.\rangle} \|v\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}}.$$
Hence the angle depends on the chosen inner product, just don't mix it with the dot product.  One omits the indices "${}_{\langle.,.\rangle}$" in case the context is not ambiguous.